# strptime not converting character to time properly. Do I need a regexp first?

Tags: regex, r, strptime

I am trying to get a series of character data converted to date time. strptime() is turnning everying into `NA`s.

Here is a bit of the data from a data.table:

```
head(dt$time2)
[1] "4/3/2012 16:00" "4/3/2012 17:00" "4/3/2012 18:00" "4/3/2012 19:00" "4/3/2012 20:00"
[6] "4/3/2012 21:00"
```

WHen I try and convert with:

```
dt[,time2:=as.POSIXct(strptime(dt$time2, "%m/%d/%y %H:%M:%S"))]
```

I end up with NA for all of `dt$time2`. If I leave off the `%S`, since that information is missing from the character data, i get an error about a `Coerced 'list' RHS to 'character'`.

Any suggestions of how to approach this would be most appreciated.

Comment: If `%S` is not in your input data, why are you telling it that it's in your input data and expecting it to work?

Comment: I don't think the coerced list to character error is related, by the way; I don't get it executing this on a vector.

Comment: In addition to @Joe 's answer, if you are using the `data.table` `:=` operator to modify / create a column, you don't have to access the input columns with `dt$`, you can just do `dt[,time2:=as.POSIXct(time2,"%m/%d/%Y %H:%M")]`

Comment: Thank you all. Cant believe i missed upper case Y. Will also drom the dt$ indexing

Answer (score 2):

You need %Y not %y.

```
> dt <- c("4/3/2012 16:00", "4/3/2012 17:00", "4/3/2012 18:00","4/3/2012 19:00", "4/3/2012 20:00","4/3/2012 21:00")
> dt_t <- as.POSIXct(strptime(dt,"%m/%d/%Y %H:%M"))
> dt_t
[1] "2012-04-03 16:00:00 CDT" "2012-04-03 17:00:00 CDT" "2012-04-03 18:00:00 CDT" "2012-04-03 19:00:00 CDT"
[5] "2012-04-03 20:00:00 CDT" "2012-04-03 21:00:00 CDT"
```